# what does the following tr command do?

Tags: shell-script, tr, ascii

I am looking at a .sh script and one of the lines is the following:

```
tr -d '\15' < file1.txt  > /testProject/files/file1.txt
```

i understood the part `file1.txt  > /testProject/files/file1.txt`  which means to add the result to /testProject/files/file1.txt but what does `tr -d '\15' < file1.txt` do?

I know \15 is an ASCAII character but not sure what it does.

Would really appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: Did you read `man tr`?

Comment: `15` is the octal value of the carriage return character; the command is probably intended to convert the file's line endings from DOS/Windows to Unix.

Answer (score 1):

The command can be evaluated as three logical parts:

- `tr -d '\15'` - This is the command that executes.
- `< file1.txt`  - file1.txt is passed as the input.
- `> /testProject/files/file1.txt` - The output is written to /testProject/files/file1.txt.

As Panki states in the comments, the [`tr` manpage](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html) has most of the info you need. The command is used to translate characters from one set to another. With the `-d` option, it deletes characters.

In the same man page, you can see a list of special interpreted sequences. The first one is `\NNN`, used to represent octal digits.

The last question is what `\15` means. You can use the `printf` and `od` commands to see:

```
$ printf '\15' | od -c
0000000  \r
0000001
```

So the final effect of the command is to remove the '\r' (carriage return) character from the input file.

As steeldriver states in the comments, this is usually used to convert from Windows-style line-endings ('\r\n') to Unix-style line-endings ('\n').

Comment: `tr` also accepts most C-style escapes, as in: `tr -d '\r'`.

Comment: Note that the command removes all carriage-return characters, even those not located at the end of lines.  It would be safer to convert text files from DOS/Windows format to Unix format text files using a tool such as `dos2unix`.